# Does my spouse need to prove knowledge of English for a UK dependent visa under skilled worker application?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, dependent-visa, language-test

I will be applying from India for a skilled worker visa for the UK. My spouse will be applying as a dependent. Does my spouse need to prove her knowledge of English for her visa? If yes, which tests will be relevant for her? I can see that knowledge of English is required for a partner (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/prove-your-english-language-abilities-with-a-secure-english-language-test-selt) but it is confusing for me whether it is for dependent or family visa.

Comment: There is an English language requirement for *settlement* applications SW44.1 / 44.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-skilled-worker